# Disable number spacing in card number field on Braintree v3.2.0

Tags: javascript, braintree

[image: example of current card number field]

Hi all,

I've read the documentation but cant seem to find a simple way of disabling the space made after 4 digits are entered in the card number field. Is there a simple option I can turn to false or will I have to edit the JS?

On some older browser its causing credit card numbers to start jumbling when clients are typing their card number in. I know braintree only supports certain browsers but people are complaining and this seems to be the only issue.

If there's not a simple option to turn false i'll look at editing the js myself, just wanted to know if there is before I start doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`formatInput` in the fields array with help you.

https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web/3.6.0/module-braintree-web_hosted-fields.html#~fieldOptions

Example:

`number: {
    selector: "#card-number",
    placeholder: "Card Number",
    formatInput: false,
},`